# Как получить день недели js?

Tags: javascript

Как получить полное название дня недели?Такой код выводит всю дату,как можно вывести только день?

```
<script>
var date = new Date();
alert(date);
</script>
```

Так можно получить номер дня, а далее с помощью if присваивать значения дня, можно ли сделать проще?

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
```

Comment: посмотрите здесь https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat

Answer (score 8, accepted):

старый проверенный способ

```js
var days = [
  'Воскресенье',
  'Понедельник',
  'Вторник',
  'Среда',
  'Четверг',
  'Пятница',
  'Суббота'
];
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
console.log(days[n]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение, если нужен номер дня недели.

```js
let date = new Date();
let dayWeek = [7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6][date.getDay()];
console.log(dayWeek);
```