# Получить из метки системного времени день недели

Tags: javascript, php

```
$day = array('Mon' => 'Пн', 'Tue' => 'Вт', 'Wed' => 'Ср', 'Thu' => 'Чт', 'Fri' => 'Пт', 'Sat' => 'Сб', 'Sun' => 'Вс');

echo $day[date("D", "1611730800")];
```

Как сделать аналогичное, только на чистом JS?

```
<script>
  var time  = 1611730800;
</script>
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы вы объяснили как работает строчка `echo $day[date("D", "1611730800")];` или добавьте тег `php` в вопрос

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить день недели js?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/963102/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-js)

Comment: `['Вс', 'Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб'][new Date(1611730800 * 1000).getDay()]`

Comment: @Евгения - массив с вс надо будет начинать.... поправил ответ. а то не так сделаете))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let days = ['Вс','Пн','Вт','Ср','Чт','Пт','Сб'];
let date = new Date(1611730800 * 1000);
console.log(days[date.getDay()]);

//-------------------------------------
// Это сегодняшний день недели: 
date = (new Date());
console.log(days[date.getDay()]);
```

Comment: Но ведь ваш код возвращает `Чт` для `1611730800 * 1000`, а `php` код `Вт`. Как так?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков видимо там тоже забыли на 1000 умножить. Но если не умножать - будет вт)

Comment: Хмм странно, добавил умножение на 1000 и так же выдает `Вт`

Comment: @ПавелЕриков пыха нездорова :D

Comment: Кстати, выдает, что сегодня среда :) а должен бы вторник :)

Comment: @Yaant да, это тоже поправил

Comment: Вы забыли про часовые пояса в ваших системах. У меня уже среда)