# Добавить class tec к текущему дню неделю

Tags: jquery

скажите пожалуйста как добавить class tec, к текущему дню недели. Например если сегодня Вторник добавлять класс к ссылке

```
<li class="sub">
            <a href="#">Вторник</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var today = new Date().toLocaleDateString('ru-RU',{weekday: 'long'});

$('li a').each(function(el){
  if($(this).text().toLowerCase() == today){
    $(this).parent().addClass('today');
  }
})
```

```css
.today{
  color: red;
}
a{
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Понедельник</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Вторник</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Среда</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Четверг</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Пятница</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Суббота</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Воскресенье</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Не проходит https://i.imgur.com/VCd4wPf.png

Comment: Разобрался спасибо

Comment: Вот на моем телефоне ваш код не работает. Потому что не поддерживается ru-RU

Comment: @AzizUmarov , очень даже может быть. Метод с массивом названий понадёжней будет.

Answer (score 2):

Способов добраться много. Предложу такой

```
$("li.sub>a:contains('Вторник')").parent().addClass("tec")
```

```js
var days = [ 'Воскресенье', 'Понедельник', 'Вторник', 'Среда', 'Четверг', 'Пятница', 'Суббота' ]; 
var d = new Date(); 
var n = d.getDay();
var today = days[n];

$(`li>a:contains('${today}')`).parent().addClass('today');
```

```css
.today{
  color: red;
}
a{
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Понедельник</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Вторник</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Среда</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Четверг</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Пятница</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Суббота</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Воскресенье</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: А как получить этот Вторник?

Comment: Вот так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/963102/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-js

Comment: Так сделать?
var days = [
  'Воскресенье',
  'Понедельник',
  'Вторник',
  'Среда',
  'Четверг',
  'Пятница',
  'Суббота'
];
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
$("li.sub>a:contains('(days[n])").addClass("tec")

Comment: $(`li.sub>a:contains('${days[n]}')`).parent().addClass("tec")

Comment: ` ковычка обратная. Форматированная строка

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: $("li.sub>a:contains('${days[n]}')").parent().addClass("tec")

Comment: @ВиталийМукменёв вот так я имел ввиду